# How to load multiple types (formats) of dynamic readers into one FME workspace?

Tags: fme-form

This is a follow up to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93579/how-to-efficiently-change-all-source-output-files-in-an-fme-workspace):

I am trying to find the a workflow that will define dynamic schema readers from a blank workspace - that is to say, without using the "Generate work space" option.

The "Generate Workspace" option seems to only allow for the definition of one type of type (i.e. format) of reader (such as raster). I am trying to figure out how to load many sorts of dynamic readers (raster, shape file, point cloud) into one workspace. As far as I can tell the "add reader" button on the toolbar will only add a static reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **[help page](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Workbench/Default.htm#adding_source_datasets.htm)** should get you going.

The key is to change the Workflow Options to Single Merged Feature Type.  Also look at the section on Adding Multiple Readers.  There are some options there that might assist you.

Comment: it seems that "Single Merged Feature Type" still requires the files to be the same format (mine are different formats), unless Ive misunderstood something. I read the section about "Adding Multiple Readers", which states: "To add readers of differing format and schema, or readers of the same format and schema but for which other dataset settings need to be different, select Readers > Add Reader from the menu bar." - which leads me to the same problem - I dont see how I can define a dynamic reader from that menu option.

Comment: It's not unusual to have multiple readers in one workspace.  However, if you have multiple files that are the same format, you can use the dynamic reader for that format.  You can also try looking into the "Generic" format reader.

Comment: Fezter is correct the Generic Reader is what you require http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#generic/generic.htm

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but you might take a look at the [FeatureReader](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/featurereader.htm) transformer, which lets you specify many reader aspects dynamically (e.g. by *attributes* rather than by *parameters*, or worse, hard-coded), and only actually attempt to read features using that transformer *if and when* a feature enters it (allowing for more dynamic choices as to what readers are actually activated).