# Looping through directory to use gdb with current date from folder using FME BatchFile

Tags: fme-form, batch

I created a batch file using the command line from the FME workspace and need to run it through a task scheduler. The file gdb is a parameter that needs to change in this batch file on every run. I am not sure if is there a way to loop through a folder and select the current gdb from the folder.

```
"C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe" "D:\Workspace_features\Country_NEW_APM updates_FeaturesOnly.fmw" TRANSACTION_TYPE_GEODATABASE_SDE "VERSIONING" VERSION_GEODATABASE_SDE "DBO.SarahS_APM_edits_Country_006" geodb "G:\APM_DOWNLOADS\Country\Country_Bulk_2022-05-01_22-43-59\Country_Bulk_2022-05-01_22-43-59.gdb"

PAUSE
```

---

I have tried Workspace runner and I used Directory and path reader it works that way but we needed to run these workspaces through a task schedular and trigger these every morning as there are almost 15 markets to run every day.

If I use Python Creator and searches all gdb will I be able to put those task on the scheduler?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30253/276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

1. Get a list of all GDBs in a directory
2. Sequentially process all of them using an FME process, something akin to a traditional loop in programming.

If those are true, to accomplish this without python is fairly simple.

[Workspace Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q0dCnguWU2_cHy8HMn1geg4rSsDMvzkG/view?usp=sharing)

**Setup Example:** Assuming we have a folder called "GDBs" with ten FileGeodatabases  inside.

[image]

**Step 1:** Create your workspace that processes the Geodatabases. For my example, its called GDBProcessor.fmw. Add an input parameter to dynamically pass file paths to reader:

1. Type: File/URL
2. Items to select: Geodatabase

[image]

**Step 2:**  Link Parameter to Feature Reader
[image]

**Step 3:** Now lets create a main workspace to call this GDBProcessor Workspace once for each of the ten GDB Inputs: Lets call this GDBProcessCaller.FMW. Here we are using a Directory and File Path name reader to read the Windows Path of each GDB in the main folder, so we end up with ten records. We pass these ten records with file paths to the Workspace runner, calling the GDBProcessor once for each input path, and passing the input path into the workspace via the parameter we created in step 1
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
cd G:\APM_DOWNLOADS\Country\Country_Bulk_2022-05-01_22-43-59
for /D %%i in (*.gdb) do "C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe" "D:\Workspace_features\Country_NEW_APM updates_FeaturesOnly.fmw" TRANSACTION_TYPE_GEODATABASE_SDE "VERSIONING" VERSION_GEODATABASE_SDE "DBO.SarahS_APM_edits_Country_006" geodb "G:\APM_DOWNLOADS\Country\Country_Bulk_2022-05-01_22-43-59\%%i"
```

I haven't tested this.

Rather than have the batch file loop through the directory to get the file geodatabases, perhaps try using Python within your FME workspace. Maybe kick off the whole thing with a pythonCreator transformer which searches for all file geodatabases in a folder and returns the path to each and save that as an attribute. The attribute becomes a parameter in a FeatureReader which reads the file geodatabase.

Or, use a WorkspaceRunner and pass them into another workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add another option in here, using scripted parameters.

**[Workspace Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wf6tYk_fjCbnEP87llE-CC6fTrqoZmco/view?usp=sharing)**

1. Create one parameter that allows you to input a folder, this will be the root directory containing all GDBs

[image]



2. add a scripted parameter that uses python os.walk to return all files or folders
[image]

```
#Code Sample
import fme
import os
path = FME_MacroValues['p_GDBFolder']
folders = []
for directory, folder, files in os.walk(path):
    folders.extend([directory+f for f in folder])
return ",".join(folders)
```

3. Use an attribute creator to create the file list attribute from parameter value. You will need to do cleanup from here

[image]